# Uploading in IE fails while using jQuery to click on the input tags for file and submit in a form

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, file-upload

So I am trying to get this uploading script to work inside of IE.  It works fine in other browsers but when I try it in IE the form doesn't submit.  I am using jQuery and CSS to build my own form instead of using what the  and  tags show, and then i use jQuery to click on those  tags.  However in IE when I select a file and submit the form, IE says there is nothing in the file input and doesn't run the PHP script specified in the action attribute of the form.  Any ideas?  I haven't been able to find any help for this just by searching.

Comment: You need to add the relevant code in your question, otherwise it is just guessing game.